# Not able to centralize the content in website

Tags: html, css

I am new to website building and using a pre-built website in the below code it is showing the four sections of the pricing and I want to show three sections in total in centralized way but when I hide one pricing all gets aligned to the left side of the webpage.

How should I resolve it ?

Is there anything else need to be shared?

```html
<section id="pricing" class="pricing">
    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <header class="section-header">
            <h2>Pricing</h2>
            <p>Check our Pricing</p>
        </header>

        <div class="row gy-4" data-aos="fade-left">

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="500">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3 style="color: #000000;">Free Plan</h3>
                    <div class="price"><sup>$</sup>0<span> / mo</span></div>
                    <img src="assets/img/pricing-free.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Aida dere</li>
                        <li>Nec feugiat nisl</li>
                        <li>Nulla at volutpat dola</li>
                        <li class="na">Pharetra massa</li>
                        <li class="na">Massa ultricies mi</li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <a href="#" class="btn-buy">Buy Now</a> -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
                <div class="box">
                    <span class="featured">Featured</span>
                    <h3 style="color: #000000;">Starter Plan</h3>
                    <div class="price"><sup>$</sup>19<span> / mo</span></div>
                    <img src="assets/img/pricing-starter.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Aida dere</li>
                        <li>Nec feugiat nisl</li>
                        <li>Nulla at volutpat dola</li>
                        <li>Pharetra massa</li>
                        <li class="na">Massa ultricies mi</li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" class="btn-buy">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3 style="color: #000000;">Business Plan</h3>
                    <div class="price"><sup>$</sup>29<span> / mo</span></div>
                    <img src="assets/img/pricing-business.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Aida dere</li>
                        <li>Nec feugiat nisl</li>
                        <li>Nulla at volutpat dola</li>
                        <li>Pharetra massa</li>
                        <li>Massa ultricies mi</li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" class="btn-buy">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="400">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3 style="color: #000000;">Ultimate Plan</h3>
                    <div class="price"><sup>$</sup>49<span> / mo</span></div>
                    <img src="assets/img/pricing-ultimate.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Aida dere</li>
                        <li>Nec feugiat nisl</li>
                        <li>Nulla at volutpat dola</li>
                        <li>Pharetra massa</li>
                        <li>Massa ultricies mi</li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <a href="#" class="btn-buy">Buy Now</a> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Pls indent your code! It’s very hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bootstrap classes set.
`class="col-lg-4` instead using `class="col-lg-3`
And hide `<div>` using "Hide" class  `class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 hide"`